# How to find the event handler code location in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

All:

I am pretty new to Chrome debug tool, I am wondering how can I find where is the event handler code located? For example, when I click something on the page, but I do not know where the click event handler function in the script( say it is a very long script and possibly minified), how can I set breakpoint to catch that so that I know where those code is?

Thanks